# Birt viewer text item not firing javascript function

Tags: birt

I have written some javascript under a text item html and it is working perfectly when in eclipse birt designer. When I deploy the report to Birt viewer in apache, it does not seem to work. I am not sure if the click is not working or the javascript behind it is not working but something is wrong the I am not getting the desired result on clicking the text item

Basically, I am hiding few charts when I click on the text item (I wrote an html script to make it a button and then called a javascript function to hide a chart). It is working in birt designer but not working in birt viewer on apache

below is the button html script

```
<button type="button" 
style="width: 120px; height: 30px; color: #5a698b;  font: bold 12px Arial;
padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; background: #ddddff; text-align: center;"
onclick=" showhidetab(1,'Population','2.5in')";">Overview
</button>
```

here is the javascript function that the button is calling

```
<script>
function showhidetab(showflag,bookmark, heightval)
{
    if (showflag == 1)
    {
            document.getElementById(bookmark).style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById(bookmark).style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById(bookmark).style.height= heightval;


    }

    else
    {
            document.getElementById(bookmark).style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById(bookmark).setAttribute("style","display:inline;height:1px");
            document.getElementById(bookmark).style.height='1px';


    }
}
</script>
```

Can someone please suggest what could be wrong here

Regards
Syed

Answer (score 0):

Some quick fixes:

- Your line document.getElementById(bookmark).style.display = "block" is missing a semicolon.
- I think the id should be js3_Population... check in your browser.
- The brackets closing the else statement is missing a semicolon.

When I made those changes it worked for me. Your code is only resizing the item and not hiding it since the state of the bookmarked object is already visible. You might consider using style.display="none" to avoid holding space for hidden items.